# If child class has a variable with same name as private variable in parent what will be used?

Tags: java

I need to modify some functionality of a class in a jar file.
Because I need to retain most functionality, I thought of extending the needed class and overriding the methods that should change.

But some of the variables are declared private so I cannot access them.
Therefore what happens if I declare an Object with the same name in child class?
(see example)

```
package abc;

class Parent {
  private Object var;

  String func_1() {
      //do something to var
      func_2();
  }

  void func_2() {
    //do something to var
  }
}
```

And the child class :

```
package abc;

class Child extends Parent {
  private Object var;

  /* @Override */
  String func_1(){
      //do something to var
      func_2();    
  }
}
```

Will `func_2` manipulate `var` of Parent or `var` of child?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happens when base and derived classes share a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630486/what-happens-when-base-and-derived-classes-share-a-variable)

Comment: Why don't you test it? Assign different values to each private variable, and print the variable value in `func_2`. Or use your debugger.

Comment: As far as `Child` is concerned `Parent.var` doesn't exist. As far as `Parent` is concerned, `Child.var` doesn't exist. Each use their own value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`func_2` will manipulate `var` of `Parent`, since you can't override a class member and `func_2` is only implemented in `Parent`.

On the other hand, any code in the `Child` class would manipulate `var` of the `Child` class.

Comment: Thank you. So is there anyway I can access var from Parent in Child class?

Comment: @Sachini There is no conventional way to do it. I think you can do it with reflection, but if the Parent var was declared private, it is not meant to be accessed by sub-classes, and you should respect that. It might not even exist in future versions of the Parent class, so your code shouldn't depend on it.

Answer (score 1):

Private members are visible only inside the defined class. So `func_2` will use `var` from `Parent` class.

Comment: Thank you. So is there anyway I can access var from Parent in Child class?

Comment: @Sachini no. The key is in `private`. You _can_ use reflection, but that is just a dirty hack.

Comment: @Sachini, without changing the scope of the varible, you can't. Or else, you have to use reflection