# The value of x here returns 5, but why?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

Why is the output here is 5 but not 15?
According to the code value of x is modified with 15:

```
class A {
    int x = 5;

    public int getX() {
        return this.x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

}

class B extends A {
    int x = 10;

    public B() {
        this.x = 15;
    }

}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B a = new B();
        System.out.println("hello" + a.getX());
    }
}
```

Is it because of the scope of the variable?

Comment: If what you're saying is really happening, it must be because of the initialization sequence.  The fix is to initialize your state from the constructors, where you can visibly control the order in which things happen.

Comment: Just go through this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630486/what-happens-when-base-and-derived-classes-each-have-variables-with-the-same-nam

Answer (score 2):

You redeclared `x` again in `B`:

```
class B extends A {
    int x = 10; // <--- here
```

This creates two fields called `x`. I will refer to them as `A.x` and `B.x` from now on. Note that `B.x` hides `A.x`. This means that if the compile time type of the variable is `A`, you can only access `A.x`, whereas if the compile time type is `B`, you can only access `B.x`.

When you do `new B()`, `A.x` gets initialised to `5`. `B.x` gets set to `15` in the constructor. Simple so far.

But then you called `getX()`. Note that this is a method from `A`. It does not know the existence of `B.x` because inside it, the compile time type of `this` is `A`. So *inside `getX`*, `this.x` means `A.x`. This is why `5` is returned.

To output `15`, you can just access `B.x` directly:

```
System.out.println(a.x);
```

Alternatively, `B` can override `A.getX` and `A.setX` to return and set `B.x`:

```
class B extends A {
    int x = 10;

    public B() {
        this.x = 15;
    }

    @Override
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    @Override
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

a.getX() calls the get method of super class and thus returns the value of x in class A.

When you add getter in class B you get value of x as 15.

```
class A {
    int x = 5;

    public int getX() {
        return this.x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

}

class B extends A {
    int x = 10;

    public B() {
        this.x = 15;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return this.x;
    }

}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B a = new B();
        System.out.println("hello" + a.getX());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't reinitialize variable in subclass which exists in superclass. This way when getting x it will return the x value of superclass instead of value of subclass. So in B class instead of `int x = 10` use `x = 10`

Answer (score 1):

The getX() is not defined in the class B, so it will refer the super class for the reference of the method, since the reference is found in the super class it will execute the method getX() of super class.

If you add getX() in class B then the same will be executed.

```
class A {
    int x = 5;

    public int getX() {
        return this.x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

}

class B extends A {
    int x = 10;

    public B() {
        this.x = 15;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return this.x;
    }

}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B a = new B();
        System.out.println("hello" + a.getX());
    }
}
```

This results 15.