# Java output explanation

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm running this Java code:

```
public class Base {
    private static boolean goo = true;

    protected String bar = "Base:" + foo();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Base base = new Sub();
        System.out.println(base.bar);

    }

    protected static boolean foo() {
        goo = !goo;
        return goo;
    }

}


public class Sub extends Base {
    protected String bar = "Sub:" + foo();
}
```

I can't understand why the output is: "Base:False". In the debugger it seems like base object has 2 members with the name "bar" (is it possible?) why does it refer to the Base bar and not to the Sub bar?

Thanks

Comment: Because you can't override fields in Java, only methods.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630486/what-happens-when-base-and-derived-classes-each-have-variables-with-the-same-nam