# Why Scala doesn't provide hiding feature like Java does?

Tags: java, scala

Java provides `hiding` features, like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5630486/11122122) describes. However, in Scala, if we consider,

```
class Foo() {
  var a: Int = 0
  
  def addFive(): Unit = {
    a += 5; print("foo ")
  }
}

class Bar() extends Foo() {
  var a: Int = 1
  
  override def addFive(): Unit = {
    a += 5; print("bar ")
  }
}

val o: Foo = new Bar()
o.addFive()
print(o.a)
```

The compiler will complain that `override modifier required to override concrete member: def a: Int (defined in class Foo)`.
So, I assume any field with the same name as the one in parent class has to be overridden?

Comment: The difference is that in Scala a public instance `var` implicitly defines a getter (`def a: Int`) and setter (`def a_=(x: Int): Unit`) method.

Answer (score 2):

In Java's case if you would wrote code like that, you would override the field as well. JVM bytecode never allows one class to have 2 methods with the same bytecode signature and if your `Bar` extends `Foo` all `Foo`'s non-private methods becomes `Bar` non-privates methods. (I'm writing non-private because `Foo` can have some `private` method and `Bar` can have method with the same name and they won't collide. But this is an exception).

The difference is that `@Override` annotation (checking that you are actually overriding something) would be optional. Scala requires you to add `override` keyword to make it explicit that you changed the behavior of an existing method as thinking that you created a new method when you overridden an existing one can be a source of subtle bugs. In Java's case quite often your IDE would also automatically generate `@Override` annotations for such method for the same reason.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. There's one place I don't understand though. In the link, if the public field, `a` is overridden automatically in Java, why we can still access the value of `a` in the parent class, i.e. `Foo` by `System.out.println(f.a); `

Comment: JVM classes have all virtual methods by default. So somewhere in each object there is a table pairing each method (name + siganture) with its implementation. When you call a method JVM checks what implementation is used for this particular object. When you inherit you extend that table with methods that the the child class introduced. Overrides just changes the implementation this table points to, but all the existing calls to the parent method are still valid, they are pointing to the same entry in table, it's just its content changed.

Comment: In fact, it seems that Scala doesn't allow overriding mutable variable as it will complain ```mutable variable cannot be overridden:
def a: Int (defined in class Foo)```

Comment: `var`iables are generated getters and setters. Java and JVM has _no_ concept of attribute override at all. So Scala can decide how to implement them in a way that won't e.g. break Liskov substitution principle.